# CloudFront links to original AWS EB Application hostname when using Java Data Rest Pagination

Tags: reactjs, spring, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-cloudfront

I'm hosting my Java Backend REST application on AWS Elastic Beans. This app is further connected to AWS CloudFront in order to be able to access it from my Next.js Frontend (which is hosted on Vercel) over HTTPS.

The data I'm requesting from the Java Backend is paginated with the help of Java Data Rest.  Everything worked great on localhost, but when I tried it in production environment described above, CloudFront links to the original Elastic Beans HTTP hostname, which I cannot use.

For example, making a GET Request to https://**[cloudfronthostname]**.cloudfront.net/api/transactions returns the following:

```
{
"_embedded": {
"transactions": [
{
"whalealertId": 1791512853,
"blockchain": "ethereum",
"symbol": "usdt",
"amountUsd": 999965,
"timestamp": "2022-02-01 13:03:05",
"amount": 999965,
"fromAddress": "28c6c06298d514db089934071355e5743bf21d60",
"fromOwner": "binance",
"fromOwnerType": "exchange",
"toAddress": "123fbf8b17d51736964afbee65aa5774858468e0",
"toOwner": null,
"toOwnerType": "unknown",
"transactionCount": 1,
"hash": "19cdfde633f34a9696ee3f6ec44c5511cb5e8043e670bfee08570519b7ed25b9",
"createdAt": "2022-02-01 11:08:03",
"updatedAt": "2022-02-01 11:08:03",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/1"
},
"transaction": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/1"
},
"whaleAlertRequest": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/1/whaleAlertRequest"
}
}
},
{
"whalealertId": 1791512784,
"blockchain": "tron",
"symbol": "usdt",
"amountUsd": 2937500,
"timestamp": "2022-02-01 13:03:42",
"amount": 2937500,
"fromAddress": "TYDzsYUEpvnYmQk4zGP9sWWcTEd2MiAtW6",
"fromOwner": "ftx",
"fromOwnerType": "exchange",
"toAddress": "TRNkKvzJv8pWoDSH93YGTXzGpgL4NLwfkf",
"toOwner": null,
"toOwnerType": "unknown",
"transactionCount": 1,
"hash": "1dc9c61654070d3c20da51954ba087e6468c95f1adf1eae9bbf2abd7cf352792",
"createdAt": "2022-02-01 11:08:03",
"updatedAt": "2022-02-01 11:08:03",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/2"
},
"transaction": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/2"
},
"whaleAlertRequest": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/2/whaleAlertRequest"
}
}
},
{
"whalealertId": 1791513156,
"blockchain": "ethereum",
"symbol": "eth",
"amountUsd": 823994,
"timestamp": "2022-02-01 13:04:27",
"amount": 299.994,
"fromAddress": "4976a4a02f38326660d17bf34b431dc6e2eb2327",
"fromOwner": "binance",
"fromOwnerType": "exchange",
"toAddress": "34af96b2c7df3a52dca2182dd0d64b3a3e7cca0c",
"toOwner": null,
"toOwnerType": "unknown",
"transactionCount": 1,
"hash": "690b71e37ed1a0f3f42f45b5b2cc8635e83b9904af11d9a85f2d10338c14d6c7",
"createdAt": "2022-02-01 11:08:04",
"updatedAt": "2022-02-01 11:08:04",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/3"
},
"transaction": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/3"
},
"whaleAlertRequest": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/3/whaleAlertRequest"
}
}
}
}
]
},
"_links": {
"first": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions?page=0&size=15"
},
"self": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions"
},
"next": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions?page=1&size=15"
},
"last": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions?page=91&size=15"
},
"profile": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/profile/transactions"
},
"search": {
"href": "http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/search"
}
},
"page": {
"size": 3,
"totalElements": 1370,
"totalPages": 92,
"number": 0
}
}
```

Trying to request https://[cloudfronthostname].cloudfront.net/api/transactions?page=1 doesn't work, I receive the same data that is on page 0.

I also have custom methods defined in a `PagingAndSortingRepository` such as

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = ?1 ORDER BY amount_usd DESC",
            countQuery="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = ?1 ORDER BY amount_usd DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    public Page<Transaction> findAllByYearOrderByAmountDesc(String theDate, Pageable p);
```

but the data is only accessible over the HTTP address `http://[EBhostname].elb.amazonaws.com/api/transactions/search/findAllByDayOrderByAmountDesc?theDate=2022-02-01&page=0`

Trying to request over the CloudFront hostname returns an empty array.

Has anyone encountered and solved this issue?

Comment: CloudFront isn't doing that. CloudFront would never modify a JSON response like that. CloudFront is just passing along what your server sent it. Your Spring server is returning those values. You need to configure your Spring server to be aware of what domain name it should use in responses like that.

Comment: @MarkB that makes sense, I'll look into it, thank you. Does that also explain why my custom methods defined in TransactionRepository don't return any data?

Comment: No, I'm not sure why you are getting different results requesting those endpoints through CloudFront. That's most likely due to a misconfiguration of CloudFront caching. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html Make sure you have configured "Forward query strings to the origin, and cache based on all parameters in the query string."

Comment: Awesome! This was it. Setting Cache Policy to "Caching Disabled" and Origin Request Policy to "AllViewer" solved both issues. Now pagination on default enpoints works, as well as my custom endpoints return the correct data.
Also, the server now returns the correct links in the JSON.

You may post an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't say to completely disable caching. Why use CloudFront if you are going to disable caching?

Comment: At least for now, I'm mainly using CloudFront to get the HTTPS hosting for the Vercel app to be able to connect to the backend.

Comment: I've enabled "CachingOptimized", so the change that solved my issue was probably just setting Origin request policy to "AllViewer".

Comment: Ok, this is really back and forth. Apparently, enabling "CachingOptimized" changed the behavior of my paginated table. Now, it seems that CF is caching the data from my first request for page 0 and returning it for all the other pages as well. I changed it back to "Caching Disabled" and I'll do more research on that, that's on me. But until then, it serves its purpose. Thank you!

Comment: As I said earlier, you have to enable caching by URL parameters.

Comment: OK, I've created a custom Caching Policy that includes query strings in the cache key. What seems weird to me is that both "CachingDisabled" and "CachingOptimized" don't include query string in the key, yet "CachingDisabled" generates the expected behavior in my app, while "CachingOptimized" doesn't.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "CachingDisabled" not including the query string in the key. If caching is disabled, there is no cache key.

Comment: Per [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html), "CachingDisabled" is a predefined option for Cache Policy in CF configuration which states that "Query strings included in the cache key: None". So does the "CachingOptimized" option.

Comment: Yeah but if the caching is disabled, it doesn't matter what the key is, the key isn't cached, so you won't get the wrong cached value returned ever, which is the whole error you were encountering.